# How do I activate my Bluetooth adapter?

Tags: bluetooth

The bluetooth adapter on my Dell Inspiron 1525 is not present

This what I have tried:

`sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source`

but I get the message  there is no such package...

How do I activate it?

Answer (score 0):

The command you tried above would remove the source code for a wifi driver, and wouldn't have any effect on bluetooth (or on wifi since it's source code rather than the actual driver).

To enable bluetooth, go to **System Settings** -> **Bluetooth**, and set the slider to "On".